# RHEL 6.1 yum hangs on "Updating Red Hat repositories."

Tags: linux, rhel, yum

I just registered my RHEL 6.1 system using rhn_register. However, when I try to run any "yum" command, it gets stuck on "Updating Red Hat repositories" and never does anything.

BTW I can run this command successfully:

```
curl -v -k https://subscription.rhn.redhat.com/subscription/ --cacert /etc/rhsm/ca/redhat-uep.pem
```

Here is the output of `rhn_check -vvv`:

```
D: opening  db environment /var/lib/rpm cdb:mpool:joinenv
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages rdonly mode=0x0
D: locked   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages
D: loading keyring from pubkeys in /var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/*.key
D: couldn't find any keys in /var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/*.key
D: loading keyring from rpmdb
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Name rdonly mode=0x0
D: added key gpg-pubkey-fd431d51-4ae0493b to keyring
D: added key gpg-pubkey-2fa658e0-45700c69 to keyring
D: added key gpg-pubkey-5ebd2744-418ffac9 to keyring
D: Using legacy gpg-pubkey(s) from rpmdb
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Providename rdonly mode=0x0
D: do_callpackages.checkNeedUpdate('rhnsd=1',){}
D: opening  db environment /var/lib/rpm cdb:mpool:joinenv
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages rdonly mode=0x0
D: loading keyring from pubkeys in /var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/*.key
D: couldn't find any keys in /var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/*.key
D: loading keyring from rpmdb
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Name rdonly mode=0x0
D: added key gpg-pubkey-fd431d51-4ae0493b to keyring
D: added key gpg-pubkey-2fa658e0-45700c69 to keyring
D: added key gpg-pubkey-5ebd2744-418ffac9 to keyring
D: Using legacy gpg-pubkey(s) from rpmdb
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Providename rdonly mode=0x0
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Providename
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Name
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages
D: closed   db environment /var/lib/rpm
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin
Config time: 0.065
D: login(forceUpdate=False) invoked
D: readCachedLogin invoked
D: Checking pickled loginInfo, currentTime=1412700762.46, createTime=1412697595.36, expire-offset=3600.0
D: readCachedLogin(): using pickled loginInfo set to expire at 1412701195.36
D: rpcServer: Calling XMLRPC up2date.listChannels
Setting up Package Sacks
pkgsack time: 0.295
rpmdb time: 0.000
repo time: 0.000
D: local action status: (0, 'rpm database not modified since last update (or package list recently updated)', {})
D: rpcServer: Calling XMLRPC registration.welcome_message
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Providename
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Name
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages
D: closed   db environment /var/lib/rpm
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `rhn_check -vvv` ? That will print out each step the yum plugin for rhn is taking in trying to retrieve the repository information. Be forewarned, it's going to be a lot of output but will at least tell us exactly where it's hanging up.

Comment: Isn't 6.1 past its EOL? (Meaning, possibly the repositories aren't around anymore?)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I posted the output of rhn_check but nothing stands out

Comment: @JoelDavis I doubt the repositories are taken offline...I have RHEL5 servers that can still update.

Comment: sorry i mixed up who the comments were addressed to :\

Comment: do you have a license?

Comment: @jgr208 yes of course, the first line in my post says that I just registered the system with RHN

Comment: hmm, so it looks like the plugin can check in with the Satellite/RHN. It's possible the problem with `yum` then. Can you post the full output of your `yum` command?

Comment: could you also post the yum repo sites